# Pandas - Faster way to find indices in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I've been trying to flag values in a feature if they are in a list. The way I am doing is very inefficient.

- I'm iterating all the values inside the list
- Finding their indices
- Set 1 to the corresponding index in the `flag` feature.

It takes about 14 minutes for a 1 million row dataframe to finish this loop. This is my code.

```
df_train['flag'] = 0

for value in big_list:
    for df in [df_train, df_test]:
        idx = np.where(df['feature'] == value)
        df.loc[idx[0], 'flag'] = 1

CPU times: user 14min 48s, sys: 3.46 s, total: 14min 51s
Wall time: 14min 52s
```

Is there any way to achieve this with set operations and `in` operator in **O(1)** time or any slighly faster solution?

Comment: do you need `df['feature'].isin(big_list).astype(int)`??

Comment: Yes that worked. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: ahh, glad it worked. However this question has been asked before so I will close this :)